# Hubspot Email templating not responsive in Gmail app

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, hubspot

Currently, I'm working on an e-mail template in HubSpot but I came across a problem that I can't seem to find a fix for.

```
<table class="two-col-centered" style="line-height: 1.5em; max-height: 309px;">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 40%; font-size: 12px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" valign=top class="k-700-col mk-padding">
        <table style="width: 100%;"><tr>
            <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 00px;">
                {% if widget.Image.src %}
                    <img src="{{ widget.Image.src }}" width="309px;" height="269px" alt="{{ widget.Image.alt }}">
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr></table>
    </td>

    <td style="width: 60%; font-size: 12px; padding: 0; background-color: #ED4A2F;" valign=top class="k-700-col mk-padding;">
        <table style="width: 100%;"><tr>
            <td style="padding: 25px 30px;">
                <h2 style="font-size: 20px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #fff;">{{ widget.heading_right }}</h2>
                <span style="display: block; background-color: #fff; width: 5em; height: 5px;  border: none;"></span>
                {{ widget.content_right }}
                {{ widget.CTA }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

</tr>
```

This is the code currently in HubSpot for the particular part that isn't responsive in the Gmail app.

[Android Gmail app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Ois.png)

[iOS app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbM4u.png)

[Outlook 2016 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l546o.png)

[Outlook Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAOp1.png)

Ideally, I would like to have the Android Gmail app like the iOS app...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android Gmail app does not support media queries.

- https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6184-media-query-support-for-gmail-app-on-lollipop-does-it-work-for-you
- https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/troubleshooting-gmails-responsive-design-support-ad124178bf81

Outlook does not support a value like this in tables: `width="309px;"` Use `width="309"` instead.

Good luck.